# Conditional if clause in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

Please consider below file:

```
foo,1000,boo,A
foo,1000,boo,B
foo,1001,boo,B
foo,1002,boo,D
```

And we have below rules:

```
If $2 equal 1000, $4 should be equal A
If $2 equal 1001, $4 should be equal B
If $2 equal 1002, $4 should be equal C
```

I want to apply the above rules to a single `awk` command, where if `$4` does not obey, print the record.

The desired output would be:

```
foo,1000,boo,B
foo,1002,boo,D
```

I tried with:

```
awk -F, '{if(($2==1000 && $4!=A) || ($2==1001 && $4!=B) || ($4==1002 && $4!=C)){print $0}}'
```

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: I Forgot to mention the code I used: `awk -F, '{if(($2==1000 && $4!=A) || ($2==1001 && $4!=B) || ($4==1002 && $4!=C)){print $0}}'` 
yet it retrieve nulls.

Comment: ($2==1000 && $4!=A) this means $2 equal to 1000 and $4 NOT equal to A. but your 1st rule states something else

Comment: @ShravanYadav Not something else, what I need to get is the records that do not match that rule, and that what was mentioned in the question.

Comment: Why didn't you just *fix* [your first version of this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225168/conditional-if-clause-with-awk-script)?  Why did you delete it and reask it?  (Google has [cached the first version of the question here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:k-BSLmrglWoJ:unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225168).)

Comment: @Scott it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
awk -F, '($2==1000 && $4!="A") || ($2==1001 && $4!="B") || ($2==1002 && $4!="C")' file
```

In the curvy brachets are the 3 conditions; if one of them applies the line will be printed. The conditions inside the brackets are connected with a AND, so both must apply.

Comment: I tried this code before, yet it retrieve nulls

Comment: @Azizieh7 what is your `awk` version?

Comment: @Azizieh7  `A` means variable A,  and  `"A"` means string A

Comment: @chaos GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: @Azizieh7 I tested with gawk 3.1.8 and mawk 1.3.3: both worked. Have you copied the **exact** command from my answer?

Comment: I Found the problem, it was in the encoding, solved when using `tr -d '\'`

Answer (score 3):

The long|many terms better put into array:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{a[1000]="A";a[1001]="B";a[1002]="C"}$4!=a[$2]' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with `egrep`:

```
egrep -v '.*,((1000,.*,A)|(1001,.*,B)|(1002,.*,C))' filename
```

Will match all lines that don't have 2nd column with 1000 and 4th with A, 2nd with 1001 and 4th with B or 2nd with 1002 and 3rd with C.

Answer (score 1):

use grep

```
grep -v '.1000.*.A\|.1001.*.B\|.1002.*.C' input filename
```

and your awk will be corrected as below

```
 awk -F, '{if(($2==1000 && $4!="A") || ($2==1001 && $4!="B") || ($2==1002 && $4!="C"))print $0}' inputfilename
```

Comment: The `grep` version doesn't adequately identify the fields. eg it should (but doesn't) output lines such as: `foo,21000,boo,A`, `foo,1000,boo,ZA`, `foo,1000,boA,C`